# How can I handle multiple client socket? using PHP socket_select()

Tags: php

in PHP, there is socket_select() function.

```
socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0)
```

Type of $read variable is an array of the socket.
The last variable is time-out second. 0 mean it will return right away.
As far as I understand, this method will wait for a connection on sockets. (mostly in $read.) What exactly this function does?

I was not able to find the use of `$write` and `$except` variables in any example online.
I was trying to handle multiple client sockets and I came across this method. but not easy to understand how it work to handle multiple clients. can anyone help?

Comment: socket_select -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php